# Poker Dealer Logic

Tags: excel, vba, poker

I'd like to use Excel as my poker dealer.  Here is the code that will generate 20 random numbers (cards) between 1 and 52.  Output of first 20 numbers/cards is in column A1:A20.  I'd like to have the next set of 20 numbers/cards generated in A22:A41, 3rd A43:A62, and so on.  How can the code be fixed so that it displays 1000 hands in column A with one row separating each set?  Thank you.

```
Sub cards()

Range("A:A").Clear

cardstodraw = 20

For x = 1 To cardstodraw

begL:
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2) = "=Randbetween(1,52)"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Text
    cardvalue = ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1)
        y = 1
        Count = 0
        Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells(y, 1) = ""
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(y, 1) = cardvalue Then
            Count = Count + 1
            End If:  y = y + 1:  Loop
            If Count > 1 Then GoTo begL

    Next

    Range("B1").Clear


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is somewhat convoluted (using `GoTo` is usually an indication that something can be improved). For getting a sample of size 20 from 1-52, use a modified [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
Option Explicit 'you really should be using this

Function deal(n As Long, k As Long) As Variant
    'returns an array of length k
    'consisting of k numbers in the range 1 to n

    Dim deck As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, temp As Long

    ReDim deck(1 To n)
    For i = 1 To n
        deck(i) = i
    Next i

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        'do k steps of a Fisher-Yates shuffle on deck
        For i = 1 To .Min(k, n - 1)
            j = .RandBetween(i, n)
            If i < j Then 'swap
                temp = deck(i)
                deck(i) = deck(j)
                deck(j) = temp
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    ReDim Preserve deck(1 To k)
    deal = deck
End Function
```

If you want to have 1000 hands in Column A:

```
Sub ManyHands()
    Dim i As Long
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For i = 1 To 1000
            Range(Cells(1 + 21 * (i - 1), 1), Cells(21 * i - 1, 1)).Value = .Transpose(deal(52, 20))
        Next i
    End With   
End Sub
```

**On Edit** Here is a modified version of the code, one which deals cards to multiple players:

```
Function deal(n As Long, k As Long, players As Long) As Variant
    'returns an array with k rows and players columns
    'consisting of k*players numbers in range 1 to n
    'if players = 1, then the array is 1-dimensional
    'otherwise it is 2-dimensional

    Dim deck As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, temp As Long
    Dim hands As Variant

    ReDim deck(1 To n)
    For i = 1 To n
        deck(i) = i
    Next i

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        'do k*players steps of a Fisher-Yates shuffle on deck
        For i = 1 To .Min(k * players, n - 1)
            j = .RandBetween(i, n)
            If i < j Then 'swap
                temp = deck(i)
                deck(i) = deck(j)
                deck(j) = temp
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    ReDim Preserve deck(1 To k * players)
    If players = 1 Then
        deal = deck
        Exit Function
    Else
        ReDim hands(1 To k, 1 To players)
        For i = 1 To k
            For j = 1 To players
                hands(i, j) = deck(players * (i - 1) + j)
            Next j
        Next i
    deal = hands
    End If
End Function
```

It could be used like:

```
Sub ManyHands()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 1000
        Range(Cells(1 + 11 * (i - 1), 1), Cells(11 * i - 1, 2)).Value = deal(52, 10, 2)
    Next i  
End Sub
```

Comment: You could take the return value and do whatever you want with it, including printing it in two columns. You could also modify `deal()` so that it takes a third parameter which is the number of players to deal to, and return a 2-dimensional array, so that e.g. `deal(52,10,2)` would return a 10x2 array where each column is 10 cards dealt to one of the players.

Comment: Thank you, how can we make the code print the first 10 numbers/cards in column A and second 10 numbers/cards in column B side by side (for every hand)?

Comment: I'll give a modified answer, but writing numbers to cells is fairly basic VBA. I don't mean to seem rude, but it might help to find a good tutorial. Stack Overflow is primarily a tool to help you solve your own coding problems. It is seldom that an answer does exactly what you want. You would need to modify it so that it does.

Comment: Thank you again, I struggle with basic coding and look for examples online a lot.

Comment: No problem. If you are looking for a good book to learn more, I recommend "Excel VBA Programming for Dummies" by John Walkenbach. I first learned VBA from an earlier edition of the book, and Walkenbach remains one of my favorite VBA writers.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Sub cards()
Dim cardstodraw  As Long, numberofhands As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
cardstodraw = 20
numberofhands = 50
Range("A:A").Clear
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    For j = 0 To numberofhands - 1
        For i = 1 To cardstodraw
begL:
        Cells(i + k + (j * cardstodraw), 1) = .RandBetween(1, 52)
        If .CountIf(Range(Cells(1 + k + (j * cardstodraw), 1), Cells(20 + k + (j * cardstodraw), 1)), Cells(i + k + (j * cardstodraw), 1)) > 1 Then GoTo begL
        Next i
        k = k + 1
    Next j
End With

End Sub
```